# Scala - Remove header from Pair RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new in Scala and want to remove header from data. I have below data

```
recordid,income
1,50000000
2,50070000
3,50450000
5,50920000
```

and I am using below code to read

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object PAN {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    case class income(recordid : Int, income : Int)

    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("income").setMaster("local[2]"))
    val income_data = sc.textFile("file:///home/user/Documents/income_info.txt").map(_.split(","))

    val income_recs = income_data.map(r => (r(0).toInt, income(r(0).toInt, r(1).toInt)))
  }
}
```

I want to remove header from pair `RDD` but not getting how.

Thanks.

===============================Edit=========================================

I was playing with below code

```
val header = income_data.first()
val a = income_data.filter(row => row != header)
a.foreach { println }
```

but it return below output

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@1657737
[Ljava.lang.String;@75c5d3
[Ljava.lang.String;@ed63f
[Ljava.lang.String;@13f04a
[Ljava.lang.String;@1048c5d
```

Answer (score 0):

You technique to remove the header by filtering it out will work fine.  The problem is how you are trying to print the array.

Arrays in Scala do not override `toString` so when you try to print one it uses the default string representation which is just the name and hashcode and usually not very useful.

If you want to print an array, turn it into a string first using the `mkString` method on string, or use `foreach(println)`

```
a.foreach {array =>  println(array.mkString("[",", ","]")}
```

or

```
a.foreach {array => array.foreach{println}}
```

Will both print out the elements of your array so you can see what they contain.

Keep in mind that when working with Spark, printing inside transformation and actions only works in local mode.  Once you move to the cluster, the work will be done on remote executors so you won't be able to see and console output from them.

Answer (score 0):

```
val income_data = sc.textFile("file:///home/user/Documents/income_info.txt")

income_data.collect().drop(1)
```

When you create an RDD it will return `RDD[String]` , then when you `collect()` on top of it it will return `Array[String], drop(number of elements)` is a function on top of Array to remove those many rows from RDD.